# How can I take a screenshot of a Sprite Kit View to a png-file or to clipboard?

Tags: macos, swift

I would like to take a screenshot of a Mac OS X window, containing a SpriteKit SKView.

I want to do this with Swift.

I know how to do this in iOS (with UIKit) but not how to do this in Mac OS X.

The UIKit is only available in iOS and I do not know how to get the screenshot in Mac OS X.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the "*Apple-approved*" way, but maybe this will get you going for now. It uses the standard `screencapture` command that you would use from the command-line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift

import Foundation

let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/usr/sbin/screencapture"
task.arguments = ["screen.png"]

task.launch()
```

You can add `-w` to force `Window Selection Mode` and/or `-c` to send captured data to Clipboard.

Apparently, there is also an undocumented `-R` option to `screencapture` that allows you to specify a specific rectangle's coordinates that you wish to capture. It is not in the manpage, but if you run `screencapture --help` you'll see it.

```
usage: screencapture [-icMPmwsWxSCUtoa] [files]
  -c         force screen capture to go to the clipboard
  -C         capture the cursor as well as the screen. only in non-interactive modes
  -d         display errors to the user graphically
  -i         capture screen interactively, by selection or window
               control key - causes screen shot to go to clipboard
               space key   - toggle between mouse selection and
                             window selection modes
               escape key  - cancels interactive screen shot
  -m         only capture the main monitor, undefined if -i is set
  -M         screen capture output will go to a new Mail message
  -o         in window capture mode, do not capture the shadow of the window
  -P         screen capture output will open in Preview
  -s         only allow mouse selection mode
  -S         in window capture mode, capture the screen not the window
  -t<format> image format to create, default is png (other options include pdf, jpg, tiff and other formats)
  -T<seconds> Take the picture after a delay of <seconds>, default is 5
  -w         only allow window selection mode
  -W         start interaction in window selection mode
  -x         do not play sounds
  -a         do not include windows attached to selected windows
  -r         do not add dpi meta data to image
  -l<windowid> capture this windowsid
  -R<x,y,w,h> capture screen rect
  files   where to save the screen capture, 1 file per screen
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, which is quite helpful. With Parameters "-c -l<windowid>" I can now capture any of my windows to clipboard but I cannot suppress the window title. So it is not, what i really wanted.

Comment: Excellent! Another non-Apple-approved technique to chop the title off the top would be to use ImageMagick (which is easiest to install via Homebrew) then you can do `convert screen.png -chop 0x55 untitled_screen.png` to remove the top 55 pixels where the title is.

Comment: This is correct, but you do not need 3rd party software. You can use the built-in CoreGraphic to trunc the picture, too. Perhaps someone has another idea. With iOS-Apps there is a very easy direct way via UIGraphics but this is not possible in Mac OS X or I did not found it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good chance the CGWindow capture API is the only all-inclusive way to do this on OS X as of the writing of this answer. Try:

```
    func captureWindowImage() -> CGImage {
    let window = view.window;
    let windowID = CGWindowID( window!.windowNumber )
    return CGWindowListCreateImage( CGRectNull, CGWindowListOption.OptionIncludingWindow, windowID, CGWindowImageOption.BoundsIgnoreFraming )!
}
```

Where `view` is any NSView in the window's view hierarchy.

Edit - theres another way I've posted below that uses SCNView to capture an SKScene that is more performant.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way that pivots off adding your SpriteKit scene as the overlaySKScene to an empty SCNView, then calling SCNView's snapshot method. This way produces an image with alpha, if needed, by setting both the SCNView and SKScene backgroundColors to clear.

This clipping came from a sample rendering a screenshot to disk (PNG format) every frame:

```
@implementation GameViewController

static double requestedFPS = 60.0;
static int counter;

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    SCNScene *scnScene = [[SCNScene alloc] init]; //[SCNScene sceneNamed:@"art.scnassets/ship.scn"];
    SCNNode *cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
    cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
    [scnScene.rootNode addChildNode:cameraNode];
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 15);
    self.scnView.scene = scnScene;
    self.scnView.allowsCameraControl = YES;
    self.scnView.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/requestedFPS target:self selector:@selector(redraw) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    GameScene *scene = [GameScene nodeWithFileNamed:@"GameScene"];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
    NSLog(@"scene=%@",scene);
    self.scnView.overlaySKScene = scene;
    self.scnRenderer = [SCNRenderer rendererWithContext:self.scnView.context options:nil];
    self.scnRenderer.scene = self.scnView.scene;
    self.scnRenderer.overlaySKScene = scene;
}
-(void)redraw {
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0 ), ^{
        NSImage* nsImage = [self.scnView snapshot];
        NSRect rect = NSMakeRect( 0, 0, self.scnView.bounds.size.width, self.scnView.bounds.size.height );
        CGImageRef cgImage = [nsImage CGImageForProposedRect:&rect context:nil hints:nil];
        NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test/scnRendererTest-%02dFPS-%03d.png",(int)requestedFPS,counter];
        CGImageWriteToFile( cgImage, [[self getDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]);
        counter++;
    });

    [self.scnView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

BOOL CGImageWriteToFile(CGImageRef image, NSString *path) {
    CFURLRef url = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypePNG, 1, NULL);
    if (!destination) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create CGImageDestination for %@", path);
        return NO;
    }
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image, nil);
    if (!CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to write image to %@", path);
        CFRelease(destination);
        return NO;
    }
    CFRelease(destination);
    return YES;
}
-(NSString*)getDocumentsDirectory {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}

@end
```

Comment: Sorry it's not in Swift, but translating it to Swift is trivial. Someone update the answer once that's done - k thx ;->